# How to identify last activity the user was doing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

GIVEN that the user is inside the app AND the user minimizes the app WHEN the user opens it again THEN the app is not in the last activity the user was doing..

How can I get the last activity the user was doing?

Comment: Are you aware of the app lifecycle ? you have to go into the appdelegate methods to save the state of the app, where were you earlier, this happens because your may be getting killed in the background due to the shared memory resources.

Comment: `Activity` like in android? You mean `ViewController` in iOS? are you trying to figure out how to retain the last VC? or activity in literal sense

Comment: Hello @SandeepBhandari, YES..

Comment: Whenever user comes to any screen, store it's unique name to user defaults. Once they open app again after killing it, open screen you have stored in user defaults.

Comment: Hello @ZaidPathan, My application have 250 screens, you mean, I need to save VC on 250 times??

Comment: @mannam-brahmam: In a normal case iOS by default preserves the view controller and entire navigation stack when you put the app to background and recreates it n loads it to memory when you relaunch. But this us not guaranteed, if iOS thinks there is a resource crunch it might kill your app and when you relaunch state will not be restored

Comment: But if you wanna ensure iOS app state is always maintained you have to write a quite a bit of code read apple doc on state restoration here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches?language=objc

Comment: My main intention is, For example, if user is in Settings screen and he minimized the app.. And if he tried to re-open, I need user to auto re-direct to Settings screen only instead of Default Home Screen..

Comment: To save ViewController in Userdefaults on every class/VC, that would not good according to me.. I am looking for something to achieve in any other approaches..

Comment: @MannamBrahmam in appdelegate save only the last used VC not all, this would save you time.

Comment: @MannamBrahmam That depends on your functionality. But avoid doing this if possible.

Comment: @MannamBrahmam, you may need to get such AC deleted from your brief.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get which ViewController the user ends up on

Delegate methods that can be provided via UIApplicationDelegate To implement the.

Code implementation:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // yzh_findTod Mothod is a class static method that I'm extending on my UIViewController.
    UIViewController* lastActionViewController = [UIViewController yzh_findTopViewController];
    NSUserDefaults* userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefault setValue:lastActionViewController forKey:@"lastActionVC"];   
}

+ (UIViewController *)yzh_findTopViewController{

    UIViewController* currenViewController = [self yzh_rootViewController];
    BOOL runLoopFind = YES;
    while (runLoopFind) {
        if (currenViewController.presentedViewController) {
            currenViewController = currenViewController.presentedViewController;
        } else {
            if ([currenViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                currenViewController = [currenViewController.childViewControllers lastObject];
            } else if ([currenViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
                UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController* )currenViewController;
                currenViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
            } else {
                if (currenViewController.childViewControllers.count > 0) {
                    currenViewController = [currenViewController.childViewControllers lastObject];
                } else {
                    return currenViewController;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return currenViewController;
}

+ (UIViewController *)yzh_rootViewController{

    UIWindow* window = YZHAppWindow;
    return window.rootViewController;
}
```

l hope my answer will help you